# How to extract plots as graphs in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I want to export my plots into an excel sheet file using netlogo file-write commands
The problem is it only exports the x's and y's values, while I need the plots to be graphed since I have many of them.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, can you explain it a bit more? But anyway, NetLogo doesn't have any capability of creating plots in Excel. `export-plot` exports the raw data; it's up to you to make graphs of that in Excel or in any other graphing program you want.

Answer (score 1):

The NetLogo dictionary (at https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html and in the Help Menu) has several `export` primitives. One of these is `export-view`, which exports in png format.

Comment: actually I meant export-view. will fix